# How to decode scapy's sniffer data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, network-programming, scapy

Am trying to make a sniffing program for learning and while making the code with `scapy` I see that the data is not readable.

Here's the code:

```py
import scapy.all as scapy
from scapy.layers import http
import optparse

parser = optparse.OptionParser()
parser.add_option('-i', '--interface', dest='interface', help='Interface to be sniffed.')
opt, args = parser.parse_args()

sniff_interface = opt.interface

def sniff(interface):
    scapy.sniff(iface=interface, store=False, prn=packet_process)

def packet_process(packet):
    # if packet.haslayer(http.HTTPRequest):
        # print(packet)
    anotherpacket = "".join(map(chr, bytes(packet)))
    print(anotherpacket)

sniff(sniff_interface)
```

I tried many decoding options that I saw previously answered here on stackoverflow but none of them worked which means, they didn't decode it. The closest I have been is this here.

The only time this worked correctly was with scapy's `HTTP` layer that when I ran it with python2 it displayed the human readable format.